# PHPUnit version with sub PHP 5.3.3

Tags: php, phpunit, xdebug

Im running PHP Version 5.3.13.
I installed xDebug Version 2.2.6
Im also using pear.

Im trying to install and use debugging in phpStorm 8, but when I try and start a debugging session I get the following message.

```
Process finished with exit code 1
Cannot find PHPUnit in include path (.;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\pear)
```

The big issue here is the following `PHPUnit 4.4 requires PHP 5.3.3;`
Ive checked the versions of PHPUnit back to version 4.0 and all require PHP 5.3.3

My question is this. With my current version of PHP, I dont want to update to 5.3.3 and become a problem for our production environment, but I need to do debugging.

What can I do?
Will going from php 5.3.13 to 5.3.3 have significant effects?
Is there a lower version of PHPUnit available somewhere? (its not listed on their site or in Git)

Comment: I think you should try to ask it on PHP Strom forum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Your case

Your version of PHP 5.3.13 is actually newer than version required (5.3.3, since 13 > 3) which means you can safely run PHPUnit 4 on your installation and enjoy it.

#### In general

There is no actively supported version of PHPUnit that is supported on a PHP version earlier than PHP 5.3.3.